# TOC and List of Tables takes two pages in document class book

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have this code in my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
...
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}      % Disable page numbering
\maketitle
\tableofcontents 
\pagenumbering{roman}       % Page number for special pages
\listoftables
\chapter{Early Life}
\pagenumbering{arabic}      % Page numbering starts normally
Blah blah blah...
```

and for some reason, it's causing the table of contents and list of tables to unnecessarily extend to the second page (even though the text isn't that long). Example:

[image]

Comment: Please note, when I change the document class to report the extra page is gone, but I need to use book class due to a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `book` class the ToC effectively ends with a `\cleardoublepage` whereas in the `report` class it is `\clearpage`.

```
% toclotprob.tex  SE 599872
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
%...

\let\savecleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}
% or \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} to have ToC and LoT with no page break

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}      % Disable page numbering
%\maketitle  % no title provided in OP's MWE

\tableofcontents 
\pagenumbering{roman}       % Page number for special pages
\listoftables
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\savecleardoublepage}
\chapter{Early Life}
\pagenumbering{arabic}      % Page numbering starts normally
Blah blah blah...

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Above I have saved the original definition of `\cleardoublepage` then changed `cleardoublepage` to `clearpage` before the ToC, than changed it back to the original definition to take effect at the end of the LoT. There is also an indication of the code to have no page break between the ToC and LoT.

If you use the `memoir` clas (a suoperset of `book` and `report`) you can easily specify the clearing after ToC, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem!